# Cannot connect to AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I created 2 instances, one with Amazon Linux and another one with Windows Server 2016. They are currently up and running but problem that security group is not working for some reason and I donw understand why.

For example SG have opened RDP port but I cant connect to Windows VM. What could be issue?

[image]

Comment: Did you launch the instances in a Public Subnet? (Definition: A subnet with a route table that connects to an Internet Gateway.) When you try to connect, does it return an error immediately, or is there a delay (how long?) before it returns an error?

Comment: John, yes it's one of default public subnet in region.

Comment: Just want to add that issue relates only to specific region (in my case London). If I'm trying to do the same in another region - run EC2 instance, assign security group with specific ports like SSH, RDP etc. everything works perfectly.

Comment: When you try to connect, does it return an error immediately, or is there a delay (how long?) before it returns an error?

Comment: John, I just figured that one of my provider banned these addresses on his side. I tried different provider and also VPN - all perfectly works. Anyway, thank you for help!